# Strikethrough doesn't work for menu items in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a menu item have a strikethrough style, but no matter what I do, I can't solve that. I've searched the web a lot without finding the answer.

I've tried something as simple as

```
Menu("Actions") {
    Text("Banana ").strikethrough()
    Text("Banana ").strikethrough(false)
}
```

but can't get it to work. I've tried with buttons as well, same problem. As soon as it's not in the menu it works, but not as a menu item. Any ideas what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: Standard menu does not support formatted Text, it extracts just string value, ignores even markdown.

Comment: I understand. Then I won't put more time into finding a solution then. :)